# How to automatically umount a mounted system after a certain duration if not used?

Tags: mount, ecryptfs

I am looking for a configuration that would automatically umount a mounted ecryptfs mounted folder if not used after a certain delay.

The folder is mounted with

```
mount -t ecryptfs folder folder
```

Say I want to umount it after 2 minutes of unuse.

I thought about running a background script that checks for the last access time of every file in the folder. Do you have a better method to propose?

Comment: sounds like a cron job would do you good.